# Edit the property of a generated object in powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell

I'm trying to create 8 labels, and edit the .Text property of them.

I've been searching for a while, but have not been able to find anything online. Though, I could be searching this out incorrectly.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 8; $i++)
{
    New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Label | New-Variable -name "testing$i"
    $testing$($i).Text = 'text of label'
}
```

I feel like I'm pretty close, but I've run out of ideas. I wondered if someone may have a resource, or suggestion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a collection

```
$labels = 1..8 | foreach-object { New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Label }

$labels | foreach-object { $_.Text = 'text of label' }
```

Answer (score 1):

[TessellatingHeckler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51736039/45375) shows you an alternative approach that doesn't require declaring *individual variables* (one for each label), which is generally preferable.

**If you do want label-individual variables**, after all:

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 8; $i++)
{
    New-Object -TypeName System.Windows.Forms.Label | New-Variable -name testing$i
    Set-Variable -Name testing$i  -Value 'text of label'
}
```

Just like you used the `New-Variable` cmdlet to *create* a variable by a *dynamically constructed name*, **you need `Set-Variable` to *set* it** (assign to it).

**As the LHS of an assignment, a `$`-prefixed token must be followed by a *literal* variable name**, which is why `$testing$($i)` failed.